# Synapse Analytics Lake Database Designer

Tags: azure, azure-synapse-analytics

Is anyone experiencing an issue when trying to open the Synapse Analytics lake database designer please?
It was working perfectly fine but over the last few days is refusing to open. It just spins on "Loading".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8B2x.png)

I expected designer to appear. Issue across several tenants and users. No one is getting it to work at the moment.